# Netbeans: Code formatter to CodeIgniter code standards

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

The company I am at is using Netbeans with PHP Codeigniter. Unfortunately, the default Netbeans code "Format" option does not produce the Codeigniter code standard that some of our developers want. Does anyone know of a Netbeans plugin to format code in different way, or based on different standards?

Comment: Best to be more specific. Try a couple of examples.

Answer (score 2):

Try

> Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formating

Answer (score 1):

Well maybe it is possible to style PHP code like CI does. I tried to find configuration for that (there is import feature in Netbeans), but struggled. What could be possible is to manually match CI PHP code formatting style. You need to go to Tools->Options->Editor->Formatting select PHP from "Language" drop-down menu and set required categories (Alignment, Braces, New Lines and etc.) accordingly. There are lots of configs so this could be done. On the other hand there is no way to export those settings. I have NetBeans 7.1.2. Tried exporting my default settings in case I screw something, changed some fields and imported them back, but after import my original settings were not restored. So it means it is not possible to export those settings, so it could be the reason why there are no such config on internet. So now there is no point setting all those configs: imagine if I reinstall Netbeans, I would need to select all those check-boxes again.

Lets try raising this bug in Netbeans forum...